# ¿Como instalar el build tools en android 3.0.1?

Tags: android, android-studio

Como se instala el build tools en android, ya que al crear un nuevo proyecto de android me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente ya valide si lo tenia instalado pero me sale como que si esta instalada la version correcta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Checa esto amigo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665001/androidstudio-failed-to-sync-install-build-tools

Comment: Cuando te salga el error dale a instalar y espera a que se descargue, listo...

Answer (score 1):

Parece que por default, Gradle viene configurado para usar esa versión de los Build Tools.

Si ya cuentas con una versión más reciente, puedes configurar tu proyecto para que utilice esa versión, poniendo `buildToolsVersion "*.*.*"` dentro del archivo build.gradle de tu proyecto, en `defaultConfig`.

Desde la vista de Proyecto en Android Studio, busca al build.config dentro de la carpeta app:
[image: Estructura del proyecto]

En ese archivo, añade la línea que mencioné arriba con la versión de los tools que tengas instalada. En mi caso es 27.0.1:
[image: Versión de los Build Tools]

Una vez añadida la línea, en la parte superior te dirá que tienes que volver a cargar el Build Gradle, así que presiona Sync Now:
[image: Sincronizar archivo build.gradle]

Después, ya debería estar funcionando :) Desafortunadamente, tendrías que hacer esto en todos tus nuevos proyectos. Si encuentro la forma de configurar gradle para que use por default una versión determinada, lo añadiré aquí.